# error on this two constructor The blank final field errorCodes may not have been initialized

Tags: java

```
public enum DataMatchErrorCodes {

  PAYLOAD_IS_EMPTY(100, "payload is empty or invalid payer"),
  MULTIPLE_PROVIDERFOUND("zz", "Multiple Provider Found"),
  PROVIDER_NOTFOUND(43, "provider not found"),
  PROCESS_MSG_ERROR(53, "unable to process msg");


    private final int errorCode;
    private final String errorMessage;
    private final String errorCodes;



    DataMatchErrorCodes(int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
      }
    DataMatchErrorCodes( String errorCodes, String errorMessage) {
        this.errorCodes = errorCodes;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must either provide value for the class level final variables while declaring them, or provide the value in the constructor.

If you use the first constructor, the final variable `errorCodes` will remain uninitialized, which is a compiler error.

Similarly if you use the second constructor, the final variable `errorCode` will remain uninitialized.

You need to provide values to all three variables, or make `errorCodes` and `errorCode` non-final.

---

**Update**

Instead of having these two, which do the same thing:-

```
private final int errorCode;
private final String errorCodes;
```

you can have:-

```
private final Object errorCode;
```

This `Object` type will be able to store both `Integer` and `String`. And then you'll need only 1 constructor:-

```
DataMatchErrorCodes(Object errorCode, String errorMessage)
```